# Decompressing gzip from HTTPS traffic with zlib, incorrect header check

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, decode, zlib

I'm trying to make a proxy using python that also reads the content of the requests and responses and I'm using this to do it: https://github.com/inaz2/proxy2/blob/python3/proxy2.py

But for some reason I cannot decompress any gzip compressed payloads. What I have tried so far:

```
@staticmethod
def decode_content_body(data, encoding):
    print(encoding) # -> 'gzip'
    if not data:
        return None

    if encoding == 'identity':
        text = data
    elif encoding in ('gzip', 'x-gzip'):
        try:
            data = data.encoded('latin_1')
            # data = str(data) # no luck
            # data = data.encoded() # no luck
            compressed_stream = StringIO(data)
            gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_stream)
            text = gzipper.read() # -> TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

        except:
            # data has to be bytes like object, says zlib
            # text = zlib.decompress(data.encode()) # -> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
            text = zlib.decompress(data.encode(), -zlib.MAX_WBITS) # -> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type

    elif encoding == 'deflate':
        try:
            text = zlib.decompress(data)
        except zlib.error:
            text = zlib.decompress(data, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)

    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown Content-Encoding: {}".format(encoding))
    return text
```

data is not in human readable format so it's clearly compressed with something. Proxy is working with sites that are using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely with the `data` passed to your function.

It is of type `str`, so the code you're using to read the request data has **already attempted to decode** the `bytes` data it received into a `str`. One of two things may have gone wrong:

1. it does not expect `bytes` to contain data compressed at all
2. it expects the data to be compressed using a different mechanism than the one used in reality

Hence: `str` contains gibberish!

I had the same problem when using the `stomp.py` package! In my case, the solution was to explicitly set the `auto_decode=False` parameter when opening a Stomp connection.

Hope that helps!

PS: More info on how my particular problem was solved: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openraildata-talk/IsO206F5US8